# Cannot give Idris proof with function which uses SnocList

Tags: proof, idris

I have the following function which uses SnocList

```
import Data.List.Views

takeLast : (n : Nat) -> List a -> List a
takeLast n xs with (snocList xs)
  takeLast Z [] | Empty = []
  takeLast Z (ys ++ [x]) | (Snoc rec) = []
  takeLast (S k) [] | Empty = []
  takeLast (S k) (ys ++ [x]) | (Snoc rec) = takeLast k ys ++ [x] | rec
```

It takes the last n elements from the given List.  I want to so that it is equivalent to the following function.

```
takeLast' : (n : Nat) -> (xs : List a) -> List a
takeLast' n xs = reverse $ take n $ reverse xs
```

When I try the following example proof

```
takeLastsAreEquivalent : takeLast' 2 [1, 2, 3] = takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3]
takeLastsAreEquivalent = Refl
```

I get the following error from the type checker.

```
When checking right hand side of takeLastsAreEquivalent with expected type
        takeLast' 2 [1, 2, 3] = takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3]

Type mismatch between
        with block in Main.takeLast Integer 2 [1, 2, 3] (snocList [1, 2, 3]) =
        with block in Main.takeLast Integer 2 [1, 2, 3] (snocList [1, 2, 3]) (Type of Refl)
and
        [2, 3] = with block in Main.takeLast Integer 2 [1, 2, 3] (snocList [1, 2, 3]) (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                with block in Main.takeLast Integer 2 [1, 2, 3] (snocList [1, 2, 3])
        and
                [2, 3]
Holes: Main.takeLastsAreEquivalent
```

When I run these in the REPL everything seems fine.

```
*/Example> takeLast' 2 [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3] : List Integer
*/Example> :t takeLast' 2 [1, 2, 3]
takeLast' 2 [1, 2, 3] : List Integer
*/Example> takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3] : List Integer
*/Example> :t takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3]
takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3] : List Integer
```

I know this not an actual proof but I just want to show how these work for an example I am working on.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like a bug to me. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Especially with `> takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3] = [2, 3]` resolves to `[2, 3] = [2, 3] : Type`, but `> the (takeLast 2 [1, 2, 3]) Refl`gives the error.

Comment: @AntonTrunov that is what I was thinking but I am new to Idris and interactive proof development.

Comment: @MikeHarris I'd suggest filing a new issue on Idris' GitHub.

Comment: @AntonTrunov opened an issue for this https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4332  Thanks for confirming that I am not crazy (in this respect).